# How to inject objects of the same type

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a presenter that takes some parameters.

```
public WidgetPresenterImpl(WidgetSettingInteractor stateInteractor,
                           WidgetStatisticInteractor statisticApiInteractor,
                           WidgetStatisticInteractor statisticCacheInteractor,
                           Context context) {
    mStateInteractor = stateInteractor;
    mStatisticApiInteractor = statisticApiInteractor;
    mStatisticCacheInteractor = statisticCacheInteractor;
    mContext = context;
}
```

Initialization of the presenter looks like this

```
WidgetPresenter presenter = new WidgetPresenterImpl(
                new WidgetSettingInteractorImpl(new WidgetRepositoryImpl()),
                new WidgetStatisticInteractorImpl(new WidgetStatisticApiRepositoryImpl()),
                new WidgetStatisticInteractorImpl(new WidgetStatisticCacheRepositoryImpl()),
                context);
```

I would like to use a dagger to initialize. For this I wrote a module

```
@Module
public abstract class WidgetModule {

@Binds
abstract WidgetPresenter widgetPresenter(WidgetPresenterImpl presenter);

@Binds
abstract WidgetSettingInteractor widgetSettingInteractor(WidgetSettingInteractorImpl settingInteractor);

@Binds
abstract WidgetStatisticInteractor widgetStatisticInteractor(WidgetStatisticInteractorImpl statisticInteractor);

@Binds
abstract WidgetStatisticRepository widgetStatisticApiRepository(WidgetStatisticApiRepositoryImpl apiRepository);

@Binds
abstract WidgetStatisticRepository widgetStatisticCacheRepository(WidgetStatisticCacheRepositoryImpl cacheRepository);

@Binds
abstract WidgetRepository widgetSettingRepository(WidgetRepositoryImpl widgetRepository);

}
```

But the project is not going to, there is an error

```
error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] ....WidgetStatisticRepository is bound multiple times:
@Binds ....WidgetStatisticRepository ....widgetStatisticApiRepository(....WidgetStatisticApiRepositoryImpl)
@Binds ....WidgetStatisticRepository ....widgetStatisticCacheRepository(....WidgetStatisticCacheRepositoryImpl)
```

Comment: use @Named annotation. AFAIK is the only way

Comment: Another way around is to implement some marker interface to WidgetStatisticsRepositiry and make it as the return type in one of the same return type method.

Comment: I tried to use @Named, but it still did not work. Maybe I did not apply it correctly. How to apply Named correctly to my project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this shouldn't be needed based on the comments, but given the follow-up question you asked maybe it will help. Here's what this might look like:

```
@Named("Api")
@Binds
abstract WidgetStatisticRepository 
widgetStatisticApiRepository(WidgetStatisticApiRepositoryImpl apiRepository);

@Named("Cache")
@Binds
abstract WidgetStatisticRepository 
widgetStatisticCacheRepository(WidgetStatisticCacheRepositoryImpl cacheRepository);
```

Then you could simply add the @Inject annotation on the WidgetPresenterImpl's constructor (Assuming that you have an @Provides method returning a Context):

```
@Inject
public WidgetPresenterImpl(WidgetSettingInteractor stateInteractor,
                       @Named("Api") WidgetStatisticInteractor statisticApiInteractor,
                       @Named("Cache") WidgetStatisticInteractor statisticCacheInteractor,
                       Context context) {
    mStateInteractor = stateInteractor;
    mStatisticApiInteractor = statisticApiInteractor;
    mStatisticCacheInteractor = statisticCacheInteractor;
    mContext = context;
}
```

or assuming that you want to abstract the implementation of the WidgetPresenter interface you could create a corresponding @Provides method in a non-abstract module:

```
@Module
class WidgetPresenterModule {

        @Provides
        public WidgetPresenter provideWidgetPresenter(WidgetSettingInteractor stateInteractor,
                       @Named("Api") WidgetStatisticInteractor statisticApiInteractor,
                       @Named("Cache") WidgetStatisticInteractor statisticCacheInteractor,
                       Context context) {
            return new WidgetPresenterImpl(stateInteractor, statisticApiInteractor, statisticCacheInteractor, context);
    }
}
```